# Добавить учетную запись пользователя в доменную группу

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

С помощью библиотеки Python `subprocess` необходимо через `PowerShell` в `ActiveDirectory` добавить УЗ пользователя в определённую доменную группу.
Пробую сделать это вот так:

```
import subprocess

def add_user_in_group(user, group):
    powershell_command_5 = f"Add-LocalGroupMember -Group '{group}' -Member '{user}'"
    process = subprocess.Popen([psh_link, powershell_command_5], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               text=True,
                               encoding='cp866', shell=True)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    return output, error


add_user_in_group('example@ex.ex.ex', 'For.Example.Citrix.Group')
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Add-LocalGroupMember : Group ............ was not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-LocalGroupMember -Group ....................... -Mem ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (..................:String) [Add-LocalGroupMember], GroupNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GroupNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddLocalGroupMemberCommand
```

Существует мнение, что надо использовать командлет `Add-ADGroupMember`, но как это сделать - непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

нужно установить модуль ActiveDirectory, который входит в пакет RSAT, если это Windows 10/11, то можно попробовать в PowerShell набрать следующее:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -online -Name Rsat.ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Нужно использовать такую команду:

```
powershell_command = f'Add-ADGroupMember -Server "{domain}" -Identity "{group}" -Members {user}'
```